# Python printing a sympy matrix faster

Tags: python, performance, matrix, sympy

My python code solves a linear equations system using the **`LUsolve()`** function.
This is quite fast. But the problem is that printing the solution takes very long for even little number of variables. 
This is the code I have written.

```
from sympy import * 
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_name = asksaveasfilename()
root.withdraw() 

niso=tk.simpledialog.askinteger("Value of Niso","Value of Niso:")
MM = Matrix( niso,      1, lambda i,j:var('MM_%s'  % (i+1) ) )
MA = Matrix( niso,      1, lambda i,j:var('m_%s%s' % ('A', chr(66+i)) ) )
MX = Matrix( niso,      1, lambda i,j:var('m_%s%s' % (chr(66+i), 'A')) )
RB = Matrix( niso-1,    1, lambda i,j:var('R_%s%s' % ('A'+chr(66+i),i+2)) )
R  = Matrix( niso, niso-1, lambda i,j:var('R_%s%d' % (chr(65+i) , j+2 )) )
K  = Matrix( niso-1,    1, lambda i,j:var('K_%d'   % (i+2) ) )
A = Matrix(niso-1,niso-1, lambda i,j:var('A_%d' % i))
b = Matrix(niso-1,1, lambda i,j:var('A_%d' % i))

for i in range(0,niso-1):
    b[i,0]=MM[0,0]*(1/(MA[i,0]*(RB[i,0]-R[0,i]))-1/(MX[i,0]*(-RB[i,0]+R[i+1,i])) )

    for j in range(0,niso-1): 
        A[i,j]=MM[j+1,0]*(R[0,j]/(MA[i,0]*(RB[i,0]-R[0,i]))-R[i+1,j]/(MX[i,0]*(-RB[i,0]+R[i+1,i])) ) 

X = ( A.LUsolve(b) )

with open(file_name, 'w') as logFile:
    for i in range(0,niso-1):        
        print(K[i,0],'=',X[i],file=logFile)
```

---

The main problem is that the elements of the vector **`X`** consists of many `sympy` symbols and `print()` has to convert them into strings.

Is there any faster way to print my solution?

Comment: `logFile.close` at the end must be a mistake

Comment: You might get a bit more interest if the code was copy-n-paste runnable.

Comment: @hpaulj now it should be copy-n-paste runnable

Comment: @Zorg Have you actually tried running this code? I get an error: `NameError: name 'b' is not defined`.

Comment: @AGNGazer sorry somehow I missed two lines

Comment: Perhaps you can skip this step.  What do plan on doing with these expressions?

Comment: @ptb I would like to use them in a other propgram which calculates uncertainties. So far I knwo this program needs the starting equation(s) as entered string. But if these expressions are that long, so that one cannot even print them in a reasonble time, calculating uncertainties using these will also take a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

The speed slowdown comes primarily from SymPy trying to sort the terms. You can disable this by using the `sstr` function directly with `order='none'`. For instance, with `niso = 5` for me, `str(X)` (`print` uses `str` by default) takes over 1 second, and `sstr(X, order='none')` takes 360 ms.

In other words, use `print(K[i,0], '=', sstr(X[i], order='none'), file=logFile)`

Comment: OK this is fast but for niso=12 this is still to slow and I get a memory error, so is there any other way? I tried to decrease the lenth of the expressions by inserting
    A = simplify(A)
    b = simplify(b)
    X = simplify(A.LUsolve(b))

Comment: sorry I am still seeking a method for printing this matrix for niso>10 in a reasonble time, sstr()-function helped a lot but still i havent be able to print X for niso>9 i

Comment: @Zorg I suspect it's just too big. The general form of a solution to the equation `Ax=b` is given by [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), which involves `det(A)`, which has `n!` terms when `A` is `n x n`. The result of `LUsolve` is even worse, actually, because it is not simplified. You can take a look at `X[i].count_ops()` to see how many operations it has, to get an idea of how big it is. If the program you are passing this to has matrix solving routines, that would be much more preferable (not to mention more numerically stable).